# Need help positioning a label in a context (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, core-graphics, swift3

The ultimate aim is to snap a photo with the camera, and then have an image, and a label overlay the photo, and then save out the composite of the three layers.

I have most of it working - the only part I can't figure out is how to correctly position the label.

I would like the coords & dimensions of the label to be something like (x: 0, y: 500, width: 416, height: 55), but whenever I set those coordinates, the label gets super distorted.

I also tried setting them to (0, 0, 416, 553) which are the full dimensions of the photo & overlay, but that just positions the label in the absolute center.

Here is the code I am using:

```
func generateImageWithText(text: String) -> UIImage {
    let image = UIImage(named: "9thGup-43")!

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 553)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 553))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Japan", size: 45)!
    label.text = text
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

    let customSize = CGSize(width: 414.0, height: 553.0)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(customSize, false, 0);
    imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    label.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageWithText!
}
```

Does anybody know how I can correctly position the label so that it sits towards the bottom of the composite image that I am creating?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the size of the frame and push it down.  I don't know what towards the bottom means, so I am going to say you want the label centered vertically in the bottom third of the image:

```
let frame = imageView.frame
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height * 0.67, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height * 0.33 ))
```

Comment: When you use things like "frame.size.height", what is "frame" referring to? Is that the frame that you are creating via "frame: CGRect", or is it another object in the view?

Comment: Also - it looks like you are calculating the width & height programmatically.  Could you technically just put in int values there (ie: coordinates on the screen)? I mean - I tried it previously, and I didn't have much luck... but just curious as to why that didn't work.

Comment: I am expressing the y position and height in terms of the height of the imageView.  if you always hard code it then you have to recode it if the imageView height changes.  Actually you don't need the whole frame; the height would be sufficient.